# VBA Excel - Reading data from another workbook

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

So I'm just trying to call data from a cell in another workbook but my code is just returning "#name?" when I use "cells(3,3)".

```
Cells(1, 1).Formula = "='\\Drcs8570168\shasad\[CR Status.xlsx]Sheet1'!cells(3,3)"
```

However, this does work if I write it like this

```
Cells(1, 1).Formula = "='\\Drcs8570168\shasad\[CR Status.xlsx]Sheet1'!c3"
```

Can someone tell me why? 
The thing is that I need to use something like cells() so that I can run this through multiple cells and assign the values to an array. Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cells()` is a VBA function that doesn't make sense when used in a Formula.

To refer to a cell using row and column numbers, you'll need to use the 'R1C1' reference style as described at the bottom of [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/about-cell-and-range-references-HP005198323.aspx).

Comment: Actually, I just got it to work. It looks like I had to change the end from 
[CR Status.xlsx]Sheet1'!c3"
to
[CR Status.xlsx]Sheet1'!" & cells(3,2)

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to include it in the Formula then it'll work - it was because it was literally in the cell rather than evaluated in VBA that it didn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see. So anything in the quotes would have to be whatever would work as a formula put into a cell?

Comment: Exactly - anything between the "quotes" is treated as a literal string and will appear as written. Ouside of the quotes is VBA code, which is evaluated at runtime.